# Javascript Loop Pro

Tags: javascript

I need loop the links always...looping just with no stop please help me out

```
 setTimeout(doSomething, 5000); function doSomething() { 
 document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="Visit Google" 
 document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="http://www.google.com"

 setTimeout(doSomething1,5000); } function doSomething1() {                                                                         
 document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="Visit Me"  
 document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" 

 setTimeout(doSomething2, 5000); } function doSomething2() {  
 document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="Visit None" 
 document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="" }
```

Comment: Maybe put a timeout in `doSomething2` that starts over with `doSomething`?

Comment: [Fornat your code](http://jsbeautifier.org/) appropriately, please! This is unreadable! [edit] it.

Comment: Never repeat function yourself. [Make the computer do it for you.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: JavaScript has [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop. You can wrap your code in `while(true) { ... }`, if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Data
var links = [
    {text: "Visit Google", href: "http://www/google.com"},
    {text: "Visit Me", href: "https://www.stackoverflow.com"}
], i = 0;

//Control
function loop(){
    var entry = links[i++%links.length];
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = entry.text;
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').href = entry.href;
    setTimeout(loop, 5000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TGnMt/

Quoting my previous comment: Never repeat function yourself. [Make the computer do it for you.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)  Often with this mindset, problems will eventually get easier to solve.

Comment: How much time does it need to run continuously to overflow `i`?

Comment: @PM77-1 - `Number.MAX_VALUE * 5` seconds, which is [about 2.848331383307101×10^301 average Gregorian years](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427edma2jhpcs3) (on Chrome) ;)

Comment: Can you please help me out..and on hover to timer or loop stop and on unhover starts again

Comment: @MultiSubMovies - Next time you should try to make it happen yourself first before asking: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TGnMt/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out..thanks :D I am not so good in javascript ;/